# How to get the S3 bucket information in my account, as on the image attached?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[Click to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHHhn.png)

I am looking to retrieve storage-related information from my AWS-S3 account. The information includes

- Access Key ID
- Secret Access Key
- Bucket
- Region
- Acl
- Path

Where should I retrieve this info under my account after logging in?
Thanks!

Comment: You want path and ACL of what service? for s3 bucket?

Comment: posted a solution which you solve your purpose, if it did do accept it answer so that it can help others in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

-For the `Access Key ID` you can find in `IAM` user management

-The `Secret Access Key` is the private SSH key you have created/you can create to log into your account, you would register the public key on IAM and keep the secret key to use the aws cli

-You can find the `Region` in the information for the bucket that you want to use or on the top right of the page

-I imagine the path is simply where in the bucket you want to store information so it is for you to decide

-The `Bucket` is simply the name of the bucket that you want to use

Answer (score 1):

- For region -> just check your upper right of the console you can choose any one, the default region when you access a resource from the AWS Management Console is US East (Ohio) (us-east-2).
- For Bucket `s3 -> navigation pane ->buckets -> search your buckets if not then create one in a specific region`. If you want arn of the bucket as aws identifies resources by ARN then click on bucket and go to properties.
- For Access key ID and Secret Access Key you will; `find this under IAM -> users -> select your name -> under credentials( if you don't found one then you need to create one ( by default it is not created)`
- For ACL, `choose your bucket and go under permissions`.
- for Path either it can be `/` for the bucket level permission or `/*` for object level permissions